# How to set the maximum thread count for QTConcurrent operations?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm running a QTConcurrent::Map on a list of items to perform some image processing tasks.  This works well on a machine with just a few threads but runs in to problems on machines with a large number of threads due to the memory requirements of my processing code.

Is it possible to set the maximum number of concurrent threads for QTConcurrent operations or do I need to re-code with a QThreadPool where I have more control?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: as i see QtConcurrent::Map runs with specific amount of items. Doesn't it mean amount of threads?

Comment: Well.. QtConcurrent::map runs on a collection of items yes, but it seems that the default amount of threads is equal to the number of cores in the machine, I'd like to run it with less.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`QtConcurrent::map` uses the global thread pool.

You can change its thread count with `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(n)`.

Comment: QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(n), does the job.  Thanks!

Comment: This also works for QtConcurrent::run() where the code inside is not recurrent (like ffmpeg/avlib).